# Connection timeout to S3 from a python application running in ECS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have a python ECS task running via EC2 (not Fargate). In this task, I am setting up a `boto3` client

```
cls._instance.client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name="eu-west-1",
)
```

and trying to perform a `PutObject` operation (`client.upload_file_obj` or `client.put_object`).

When I deploy this on ECS and hit the endpoint, my request seems to time-out (or memory leak) and in my logs I see

```
[2023-09-13 12:37:22 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:40) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
2023-09-13 12:37:21 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:40)
```

My ECS task has a permission that allos it to `PutObject` in the specific bucket, my ECS security group has allowed outbound traffic on both `443` ad `80` and I even tried to create a VPC endpoint for all my subnets, but nothing seems to fix that timeout. What could I be missing in my network configuration?

Perhaps it is also important to mention that my task does not have a public IP and is load balanced by an application load balancer.

Comment: What network mode is the task using? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html Also, have you tried getting an SSH session to the EC2 instance and checking S3 connectivity from there?

Comment: The task is using the `awsvpc` network mode. Initiating an SSH session to the EC2 instance, unfortunately hangs for me. Trying to figure this out.

Comment: It sounds like the EC2 instance and tasks are probably in a private subnet without network access to anything outside the VPC. If that's the case, adding an S3 VPC Endpoint should have fixed the issue. We would need exact details of what you tried with the VPC endpoint to help you debug that.

Comment: Managed to SSH into the EC2 instance and I can succesfully receive packets via `ping google.com`, so it should have a public connection. Looking at the subnet's route table it has a local target and internet gateway target.

Comment: Yes but the tasks do not have a public IP, so they can't use that Internet Gateway. You need to add public IP to the tasks, or get that S3 VPC Endpoint working.

Comment: Indeed, after changing my task type to host from awsvpc, I could ssh to the EC2 instance and execute network requests inside the container. This creates an issue for my deployments though. Should I try other task types, or look into S3 VPC Endpoints?

Comment: If by "task type" you mean "network mode" then `awsvpc` with public IP enabled would work. Or `awsvpc` with an S3 VPC endpoint. I can't answer the question of what you should try since you aren't specific about what "issues" this causes.

Comment: Managed to fix it by adding a VPC `Gateway` endpoint to `com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3` targeting the private VPC's route table.

Comment: How was that different from your previous attempt at setting up a VPC Gateway endpoint?

Comment: I think I was setting up an Interface endpoint and also my bucket was in a different region.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by setting up a VPC `Gateway` endpoint to S3.
(https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpcconsole/home?region=eu-west-1#Endpoints)

That did a couple of things:

- Added a new record to the VPC prefix list `com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3`
- Added a record to the VPC route table that points the prefix to the endpoint.

Additionally, I had my bucket in the wrong region, which was causing an issue for me, as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html

I changed my task definition to looks a bit like this:

```
{
    ...
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            ...
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "task-name",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http" // HTTP here since I use a load balancer.
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "{ECS_TASK_ROLE_WITH_PERMISSION_TO_THE_BUCKET}",
    "executionRoleArn": "{ECS_TASK_ROLE_WITH_PERMISSION_TO_THE_BUCKET}",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    ...
}
```

In my S3 requests I only specify the region and bucket names, since the `boto3` can pick up the credentials from the IAM role (I assume)

I also made sure to redeploy my task after configuring the endpoint.